# Too many redirects regex redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am on Wordpress and right now using Yoast Seo Pro which has a redirection section including a Regular Expressions redirects section.

How do I redirect say `/mycategory1/page/pagenumberhere/` to
`/category/mycategory1/page/pagenumberhere/` ?

So I only need to make one redirect that handles all possible page numbers?

I have tried `/mycategory1/page/([0-9])` to `/category/mycategory1/page/$1`
It looks like it redirects to `/category/mycategory1/page/pagenumberhere/` but there is an `err_too_many_redirects` on the `/category/mycategory1/page/pagenumberhere/` with this rule added so I have removed it again.

If you can help with code into the `.htaccess` instead perhaps I could try that.

Comment: It looks like your regex pattren is missing "start of string " the ^ character, delimete your pattern using ^ and $ chars to avoid matching the target path.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule already looks promising.

However, as @starkeen pointed out, the regular expression `mycategory1/page/([0-9])` matches every request *containing* `mycategory1/page/` with some trailing number. This is true of `category/mycategory1/page/` as well, as it also contains "mycategory1/page".

If you want to match requests *starting* with `mycategory1/page`, you must anchor the regular expression at the beginning with `^`, see [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction - Regex vocabulary](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regexvocab)

```
RewriteRule ^mycategory1/page/([0-9]) /category/mycategory1/page/$1 [L]
```